# Create Login Page with Animated SVG avatar

Tags: android

I want to create login page like animated SVG Avatar v2 form.
I have also tried with webView css, js

```
See here https://codepen.io/dsenneff/full/2c3e5bc86b372d5424b00edaf4990173/
```

Comment: This is not a question

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LottieAnimationView` to add animations to your `Views`. It is a library to render `AfterEffects` animations.

1. Import `LottieAnimationView` in your Android app.

> implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:$lottieVersion'

where $lottieVersion is the latest version that you'll get from [Lottie Android](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android).

2. After adding the library, download the appropriate AfterEffects animation from

   https://lottiefiles.com

   This is their official website to get tons of animations for lottie.
3. After downloading the animations, you can find the documentation to use Lottie below:

   [Lottie Docs](http://airbnb.io/lottie/#/android)

Comment: Not found this type of login svg in Lottie

Comment: You can create it on your own in After effects. I've told you how create a login screen like that, now it's on you how you're going to use it. Nobody's here to Google stuff for you, if you're unable to find that animation, hire a designer who'll create it for you.